# How to get list of attribute names from attribute set

Tags: php, magento

I want to get a list of names of attributes from attribute set. I know how to get attribute IDs, but I can't figure out how to get list of names. This is my code so far.

```
<?php
    $entityTypeId = Mage::getModel('eav/entity')->setType('catalog_product')->getTypeId();
    $attributeSetName   = 'Brands'; 
    $attributeSetId     = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute_set')
                        ->getCollection()
                        ->setEntityTypeFilter($entityTypeId)
                        ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_name', $attributeSetName)
                        ->getFirstItem()
                        ->getAttributeSetId();
    $attributes = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_api')->items($attributeSetId);
    foreach($attributes as $_attribute){
        var_dump($_attribute);
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did some testing myself and seem to have done it now,

```
     foreach($attributes as $_attribute){

        $attributeInfo = Mage::getResourceModel('eav/entity_attribute_collection')
            ->setCodeFilter($_attribute['code'])
            ->getFirstItem()->getFrontendLabel();

              echo "<pre>";
              echo $attributeInfo;
       }
```